# Get information from cookie created in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity.

I create a cookie holding user information like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.UserID.ToString()),
};
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var props = new AuthenticationProperties();

HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();
```

How I can get `user.FullName` and `user.UserID` from my Cookie in another class?

Comment: You have to do something like `HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity))`. You can check [this link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-cookie-authentication/) to understand more about it.

Comment: do you want to access those info from the server (in a different place) or client?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the FullName and UserID like below:

```
var FullName = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
var UserID = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
```

Be sure your middleware order should like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();      
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Result:
[image]